# Magento 2 : customer attribute not display at frontend while using print_r()

Tags: magento2, frontend, customer-attribute

Hello Everyone,
         I have created a custom attributes for a customers it's working fine in admin also save data and get data while attributes have any certain value in textbox But if attribute has not value save in textfield it will not aslo dispaly attribute name while print_r() data. so i want to get this attribute while custom attribute value have or have not save in database.

please check image for more details.

thanks

[image]

> InstallData.php

```
  use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface;

 use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

 use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;

 use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

 use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

 class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface

 {

/**
 * @var EavSetupFactory
 */

private $eavSetupFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Config
 */

private $eavConfig;

public function __construct(
    EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
) {
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
}

/**
 * Installs data for a module
 *
 * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
 * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
 * @return void
 */
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup $eavSetup */
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $setup->startSetup();

    $attributeCode = 'account_id';
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, 'account_id', [
        'label' => 'Account Id',
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => 1,
        'system' => 0,
        'position' => 100,
        'default' => 0,
        'input' => 'text'
    ]);

    $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
        CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
        CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
        null,
        $attributeCode);

    $amountId = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, $attributeCode);
    $amountId->setData('used_in_forms', [
        'adminhtml_customer',
        'customer_account_create',
        'customer_account_edit'
    ]);
    $amountId->getResource()->save($amountId);

    /***** Amount Spend **********/
    $attributeCode = 'amount_spend';
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, $attributeCode, [
        'label' => 'Amount Spend',
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => 1,
        'visible_on_front' => 1,
        'system' => 0,
        'default' => 0,
        'position' => 110
    ]);
    $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
        CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
        CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
        null,
        $attributeCode);

    $amountSpend = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, $attributeCode);
    $amountSpend->setData('used_in_forms', [
        'adminhtml_customer',
        'customer_account_create',
        'customer_account_edit'
    ]);
    $amountSpend->getResource()->save($amountSpend);
    /******* Customer Type **********/
    $attributeCode = 'customer_type';
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, $attributeCode, [
        'label' => 'Customer Type',
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => 1,
        'visible_on_front' => 1,
        'system' => 0,          
        'position' => 120,
    ]);

    $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
        CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
        CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
        null,
        $attributeCode);

    $customer_type = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, $attributeCode);
    $customer_type->setData('used_in_forms', [
        'adminhtml_customer',
        'customer_account_create',
        'customer_account_edit'
    ]);
    $customer_type->getResource()->save($customer_type);

    $attributeCode = 'tax_exempt_id';
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, $attributeCode, [
            'label' => 'Tax Exempt ID',
            'required' => false,                
            'user_defined' => 1,
            'system' => 0,
            'position' => 130,          
            'input' => 'text'
        ]);

        $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
            CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
            CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
            null,
            $attributeCode);

        $tax_exempt_id = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, $attributeCode);
        $tax_exempt_id->setData('used_in_forms', [
            'adminhtml_customer',
            'customer_account_create',
            'customer_account_edit'
        ]);
        $tax_exempt_id->getResource()->save($tax_exempt_id);

        /****** Yes No Button *********/

        $attributeCode = 'rebate_allowed';
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, $attributeCode, [
            'label' => 'Rebate Allowed',
            'type' => 'text',
            'required' => false,                
            'input' => 'select',                
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
            'global' => '\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL',
            'user_defined' => 1,
            'system' => 0,
            'default' => '0',
            'position' => 140
        ]);

        $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
            CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
            CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
            null,
            $attributeCode);

        $rebate_allowed = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, $attributeCode);
        $rebate_allowed->setData('used_in_forms', [
            'adminhtml_customer',
            'customer_account_create',
            'customer_account_edit'
        ]);
        $rebate_allowed->getResource()->save($rebate_allowed);

    $setup->endSetup();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you verify that value is saved in DB ?

Comment: no while first time created attribute has not any value so it's not display in array

Comment: Please post your code for `InstallScript` by which you have created customer attribute.

Comment: Did it work for you ?

Comment: This file is work for me it's create attribute and save data into database while click on save on from admin.

Comment: Glad to know this. If you find it helpful please give up vote and accept answer to help other members.

Comment: i have till not check it let me check that after that...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79547/discussion-between-sarfaraj-and-vivek).

Answer (score 1):

In order to get **Customer Attribute** You can try below code:

1). **Load customer by Id.**

```
$customer = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById(1);

//Use Class  \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
```

2). **Get Attribute**

```
$customer->getCustomAttribute('your_custom_attribute');

// For File type Attribute

$customer->getCustomAttribute('your_custom_attribute')->getvalue();
```

**UPDATE**

File Name is **incorrect** It should be `InstallData.php`

I didn't check your code. But I am providing you sample code that will surely resolve your issue. **Modify it as per you need.**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;


class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
protected $groupFactory;

protected $customerSetupFactory;

private $attributeSetFactory;

private $eavSetupFactory;




public function __construct(GroupFactory $groupFactory, EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
                            AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory)
{

    $this->groupFactory = $groupFactory;
    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

public function install(
    ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
    ModuleContextInterface $context
)
{


    $setup->startSetup();

    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $setup->startSetup();
    $attributesInfo = [
        'customer_avatar' => [
            'label' => 'Customer Avatar',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'input' => 'file',
            'position' => 1000,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'system' => 0,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'position' => 1000,
        ]
    ];
    $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
    $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
    /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
    foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeCode => $attributeParams) {
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode, $attributeParams);
    }
    $magentoUsernameAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_avatar');
    $magentoUsernameAttribute->addData([
        'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
        'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_edit', 'adminhtml_checkout', 'adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address'],
    ]);
    $magentoUsernameAttribute->save();

    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $setup->startSetup();
    $attributesInfo = [
        'social_status' => [
            'label' => 'Social Status',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'input' => 'text',
            'position' => 333,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'system' => 0,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'position' => 333,
        ]
    ];
    $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
    $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
    /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
    foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeCode => $attributeParams) {
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode, $attributeParams);
    }
    $magentoUsernameAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'social_status');
    $magentoUsernameAttribute->addData([
        'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
        'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_edit', 'adminhtml_checkout', 'adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address'],
    ]);
    $magentoUsernameAttribute->save();

    $setup->endSetup();
}

}
```

**PS: Don't forget to remove your module's entry from `setup_module` table if you are modifying existing module which is already registred.**

After remove entry from `setup_module` table execute

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade` from your root directory.

Comment: you are right using this code i will get custom attribute value but this "your_custom_attribute" is not display so i am not able to get value of that attribute.
plz see image i have posted.

Comment: As i said Please post you code for customer attribute so that i can check what's issue with this.

Comment: please check update question.

Comment: only this file created to create customer custom attributes.

Comment: Check I've posted `InstallData.php` sample code Which is working for me You can change it as per you need Let me know if you have any problems with this.

Comment: Not working bro